# How do I get multiple album picture urls with one call to Facebook Graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can pass the string "album.id/photos" and I get back a list that looks like this below where I have each photo id in the album, but it doesn't return the URL for each picture (just the id). Do I have to then run a single call for each picture I want to fetch the url for, or is there a way to have the urls returned with the call below?

```js
{
  "data": [{
    "created_time": "2011-01-21T20:19:49+0000",
    "id": "10150091489547705"
  }, {
    "created_time": "2010-02-03T03:31:56+0000",
    "id": "293935837704"
  }, {
    "created_time": "2009-01-02T02:46:28+0000",
    "id": "56480657704"
  }],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MTAxNTAwOTE0ODk1NDc3MDUZD",
      "after": "NTY0ODA2NTc3MDQZD"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is what my call looks like in Javascript

```js
 for (var j = 0; j < albumIds.length; j++) { 
    var request = albumIds[j] + "/photos";
    FB.api(request, 'get', {
      access_token: userToken
    }, function(responses) {
      var pictureUrl = responses.data.url; // no url returned - only a photo id

     
    });
```

Comment: Ask for the url field

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to run single request for every picture id.

Add **source** in fields of your api request which returns source url of every picture along with id.

Eg: /{album_id}/photos?fields=source,created_time

Returns output like:

```
{
"data": [
    {
    "source" : <source_url1>,
    "created_time" : <created_time1>,
    "id" : <photo_id1>
    },
   {
    "source" : <source_url2>,
    "created_time" : <created_time2>,
    "id" : <photo_id2>
   }
]
}
```

Hope this helps :)